# Tratamento de erros - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Como eu faço para que toda vez que ocorrer um erro no meu site, eu consiga escrever no log do jeito que eu definir ?

Eu estou trabalhando com wordpress então estou tentando fazer um plugin que faça isso, tentei utilizar o mu-plugins e adicionar este código:

```
<?php


/**
 Plugin Name: TESTE
 Description: testando log novo
 Version: 1.0
 Author: Vteste
Author URI: teste

-------
LICENSE: teste
   **/ 

function trataErros($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    $string = "$errno - $errstr em $errfile na linha $errline\n";
    file_put_contents('error.log', $string, FILE_APPEND);
    // se retornar TRUE não faz o tratamento padrão do erro no PHP
    return TRUE;
}
set_error_handler('trataErros');

?>
```

E forçar este erro :

```
<?php pg_connect();
$a+=5;?>
```

Mas ele não escreve no log da maneira que eu gostaria, aparentemente ele segue o padrão php e eu gostaria de alterar isso.

---

Eu tenho que fazer com que meu log seja parecido com isso :

```
[08-Jun-2017 22:15:25 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: k in D:\h\s\w\wp\t\l\r\m\l.php on line 8 - "Minha mensagem adicional".
```

Comment: Você quer alterar a forma como o PHP envia os erros ou quer enviar erros customizados também? Ou os dois?

Comment: Se possível quero enviar erros customizáveis, eu estou com site em produção e não consigo identificar quais paginas estão dando erro. 

Pela quantidade de paginas e arquivos eu não consigo baixar o site para procurar onde os erros ocorrem, então eu queria editar o log para que ele me retorne as informações que eu pedir.